# Error message "Cannot index array with string "value" "

Tags: linux, unix, jq

I am trying to produce a plot of water temperatures from this website: https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/dv/?sites=04092440&format=json&period=P520W

I was able to  get the first value using the following commands:

```
curl "https://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/dv/?sites=04092440&format=json&period=P520W" | jq .'value.timeSeries[3].values[0].value[0].value'
```

However there are total 478 values. I am wondering how can I print all the values. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the JSON from the curl call, the query:

```
jq '.value.timeSeries[].values[].value[].value'
```

returns 9,029 values.  It's hard to know which ones you're interested in.  If you wish further assistance, it would help if you could follow the http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (aka "mcve") guidelines.